# Can't connect (no TX or RX) through UART on some devices to SIM7600

Tags: arduino, uart, serial

I have 3 devices:

- An [UNO 5v](https://auseparts.com.au/SainSmart-UNO-ATMEGA328P-PU-ATMEGA8U2-Microcontroller) (non-genuine)

[image: UNO]

- An [SMS hat/shield device `SIM7600G-H` 3.3v](https://core-electronics.com.au/sim7600g-h-m2-4g-hat-for-raspberry-pi-lte-cat4-high-speed-4g3g2g-gnss-global-band-1.html) to communicate with via UART

[image: SMS Device]

> AT Manual: https://mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/documents/a7600_series_at_command_manual_v1.01.pdf
> User Manual: https://fcc.report/FCC-ID/2AJYU-8PYA007/4857209.pdf

- A [USB UART controller](https://core-electronics.com.au/usb-to-ttl-uart-rs232-serial-converter-module-pl2303hx-au-local-shipping.html) for debugging purposes

[image: UART USB 5v]

---

I can't get serial communication to work between a few of my devices. Mainly, USB TTL to the HAT, ESP32 or a software serial from the UNO.

This is the success I've had trying to talk to and from devices ✅ = working coms, ❌ = nothing on coms at all. Read left to right, **HAT serial (SMS DEVICE)** can communicate with UNO hardware serial.

[image: Connection matrix]

Notes:

- I've tried bauds `9600` and `115200` where the hat and the communicator are at the same baud.
- I can't communicate using the hardware serial on the ESP32 either.
- I can confirm all the pieces do work to some degree, as seen with the working communication in the matrix.
- I've tried two different power sources for the USB to SMS hat connection with no luck
- TX RX dip switch is set to ON side

Previous discussion was made here:

> https://forum.arduino.cc/t/cannot-communicate-with-software-serial-on-particular-devices-sim7600g-h/1077241

Why am I getting no serial connection on these devices? When connecting the USB TTL to the HAT, I don't even get the RX light to blink from the HAT's starting sequence serial message.

By no connection, I mean the serial monitor is blank.

Comment: Just to be clear; are you connecting devices with different logic levels of 5V and 3.3V together, and expecting them to work?

Comment: @Justme yes and no. The UNO hardware port was 5v and worked with the 3.3v shield port. And the ESP32 (3.3) did not work with the shield.

Comment: Connecting a 5V TXD pin to a 3.3V RXD pin that cannot handle 5V may cause damage. And a 5V RXD pin may not be compatible with 3.3 TXD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TX` and `RX` labels mirror the Raspberry Pi. So I swapped the `RX` and `TX` wires to connect as `RX`->`RX` and `TX`->`TX` and now it works